# Changing scale based on distance in processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a camera for a two player game that can zoom in and out based on player distance.

Current code to do this,

```
    float scale = 1;
    float distance = dist(player.location.x, player.location.y,     
    player2.location.x, player2.location.y);

    if (distance > 
    scale = 0.99; 
    }

    //Places the camera between the two players at all times. No matter what 
    scale the game is in.
    translate((-player.location.x * scale / 2) - (player2.location.x * scale / 
    2) + width / 2
    , (-player.location.y * scale / 2) - (player2.location.y * scale / 2) + height / 2);

    scale(scale);
```

My plan was to use a if statement but this obviously didn't work. I was thinking about using modulo to do this but i don't fully understand how to use modulo yet. Anyone got an idea for me on how to fix this problem?

The distance variable is supposed to check the distance between the first player and the second player. The moment the distance between the two players is for example hundred than the scale should change by 0.01. The scale would change from 1 to 0.99 because of the distance. How ever i want to subtract or add ever 100 dist.

```
0 dist = scale 1
100 dist = scale 0.99
200 dist = scale 0.98
ect.
```

What should i do to accomplish this?

Comment: "obviously didn't work" can you explain this further? What's it supposed to do ? What is it actually doing instead?

Comment: For now, it's hard to understand what you want to do. What does `scale(...)`do? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I have edited my post with some more context to what i want.

Comment: I would break up the problem in three separately solveable problems. First make it so that you can always keep the camera at the centroid of the two players (with fixed zoom), then manually adjust zoom and repair the translate formulas so the camera still stays centered. Then think of a nice calculation for zoom depending on the distance and it should magically work.

Comment: The camera is already centered between the two players. I do this using the translate part of my code. If i enter a zoom of 2 instead of 1 it stays in between the two players. So that isn't my problem.  The last problem you mentioned of the calculation to change the zoom based on distance is what i need. i don't want to change the zoom once based on that distance tho. I want to change it every 100 pixels distance. Sorry for being unclear about this i am kinda new to both programming and this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple linear expression will allow continuous scaling.

```
scale = max(0.1, 1 - distance/10000);
```

If you want the scale to decrease in increments of 0.01 for every additional 100 distance, use the following (it uses modulo, as you suggested):

```
scale = max(0.1, 1 - (distance - distance%100)/10000)
```

---

`max()` is a built-in processing function that I've used here to provide a floor value to the scaling factor (cannot go below 0.1).

Comment: Thank you. This helps is a better way to solve my problem for what i had first. I have changed it now to this way. Thanks to both you and Smith for giving me good answers